# Pass the name of the model from view to the dynamic partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

**GM. How can i pass the name of the model from view to the dynamic partial view
so I can use it inside the code.**

in the partial view (_gridView)

```
 <%=Html.Grid<type1>("MyDynamicGrid")
    .Caption("My dynamic JqGrid")
            .DataUrl(dataURL)
                  .ImagePath("/Content/JqGridThemes/steel/images")
                    .AutoWidth(true)
                       .ColumnWidth(80)
                        .SortOrder(jqGridMVC2.Extensions.SortDirection.Desc)
                            .RowsPerPage(5)
                               .SortName("Id")
                                .RowList(new List<int>(){5,10,20,30})

        %>
```

in the index View

```
  <% Html.RenderPartial("_GridView", new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "Name",Model }, { "Name2", "/Home/DynamicGridData/" } }); %>
```

I tried to use the **Model keyword** but apparently this isn't work. (Null)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'dynamic' keyword. Below are the steps in which you should set this up.

### 1. Controller and Model

For this example I have created a class and a action/controller. I am passing the model to the view "Test"

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public int Field1 = 1;
    public string Field2 = "Hello";
    public string Field3 = "World";
}

public ActionResult Test()
{
    var c = new SampleClass();
    return View(c);
}
```

### 2. Master View

My master view uses `@Html.Partial` to render its partial view. Also it declares what model it is accepting on that view.

```
@using MvcApplication2.Controllers
@model SampleClass
<h2>title</h2>
@Html.Partial("MyPartial")
```

### 3. Partial View

The partial view can have `@model SampleClass` and then use the fields "Field1", "Field2" and so on. But since you mention of a dynamic view you could also use the dynamic keyword.

```
@using MvcApplication2.Controllers
@model dynamic
<h4>My partial view</h4>
@Model.Field2 @Model.Field1
```

Comment: using the keyword 'dynamic' like this, do you think it is wise? Just want to have your opinion

Comment: depends on your use case

Comment: Did this work ? Incase it did please mark this answer.